# How to javascript regex match the following?

Tags: javascript, regex

I only want to match ones that say:

Given I string, I want something that is able to detect words that match anything with the following pattern of "TERMINATE:" + any number of random letters or numbers:

```
"VIRUS:XPA"
"VIRUS:IDI"
```

Then the function should return "true" to indicate there is only a virus.

But if the string is the following:

```
"ANM|SDO|FSD:SOS|VIRUS:XPA"
"ANM:SOS|SDO|FSD:SOS|VIRUS:XLS"
"VIRUS:XLS|ANM:SOS|SDO|FSD:SOS|VIRUS:XPL"
"VIRUS:XLS|ANM:SOS"
```

Then the function should return "false" to indicate there is no virus, or the virus is masked.

Can this be done with a single regular expression in javacsript?

Comment: Please improve the question - your match criteria is unintelligible at present. Is it only either `"TERMINATE:VIRUS:XPA"` or `"TERMINATE:VIRUS:IDI"` that should match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
var isVirus = /^VIRUS\:\w*$/.test(str)
```